# Why do I need a TestDriver when using Java?

Tags: java

Today, I had my first Java lecture at the university and I heard a lot about HelloWorld and a TestDriver. I somehow get the concept that the TestDriver is the class that starts you program. But what is the advantage of having a TestDriver? Why can't I just write a main method in my HelloWorld class and start it from there?

Comment: You could do that but it sounds like he wants you to get used to the idea of instantiating classes as most of the code you will write will be structured in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

Your course is probably teaching you about [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). The idea is that you should write tests for every piece of functionality and when you implement the functionality you run the test(s) against it as a routine part of the coding cycle. It's not *required* that you develop code this way (except maybe for the course), but it's a really good discipline to learn.

The `TestDriver` class (if that's what it is—it sounds like it) is the controller for running the tests.

Answer (score 1):

You may not realise it but TDD is now becoming critical in software development. Many programming/development projects or jobs now follow and require the Test-Driven development methodology because it creates code that is capable of carrying out the tasks that users really want or need or for each piece of functionality that is then tested before integration with the software. In addition, your teacher is teaching you a design methodology or way of thinking that is critical in software development. The code is not important, rather it is the way of thinking that these Tests teach you. The following [article](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html) is an introduction to the methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Having a Driver class allows you to separate your actual application logic from the "runner" code.